# Is it my modem or my ISP?

Tags: isp, cable-modem

I am having internet connection problems.

From tracert 8.8.8.8, the connection to modem is always immediate, but the router next (getting out of the modem) fails easily (Request timed out). It typically takes 10-30 min or more to get connected, although after it gets connected to the outside world, the connection stays reasonably well generally.

Is it fair to assume based on this observation that my modem is the culprit (or the actual cable that goes out), but not my ISP ?

A side question, if it is indeed my modem's issue, which seems to be common for many customers, I was wondering why modems are built so poorly generally. Comparing to cell phones, for example, it does not seem that people have as many problems with their cell phones.

Comment: No, While it’s possible the modem is at fault this is likely an ISP problem.

Comment: @Ramhound. Thanks for the input. Care to elaborate? What made you think it's the ISP.

Comment: Because your problem ping to the modem isnt the problem

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would do in your question is phone your ISP and tell them about connectivity issues, they have tools to check the connection remotely and could help you identify the problem.

From this little information you provided (it would be really great if you edited your question to specify your network topology, router and modem model) I think it can be your modem. I had a similar failure where my fiber media converter started failing due to faulty power supply and I was confused as to why I was getting 100 times less speed than I used to. After I contacted ISP they determined that there was no issue on their side, whence I found that it was my fiber media converter that started to fail and simply replaced it.

As for the side question, if your modem is provided by ISP they would usually stick to the cheapest one since there is no incentive to provide quality, feature-full modems to people that won't use those features and those people that need extra features would stick to expensive brand **routers** (that have inbuilt modems) anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Will def contact ISP to see if they see anything from their end. Regarding the router model, I actually purchased a cheap ARRIS - SURFboard. Given my current experience, totally willing to upgrade it if needs be. Not sure if it's permissible for this forum, any recommendation on solid-quality modems and routers?

Comment: @BChen Hardware recommendations are off-topic.